Redirecting in Next JS not going through middleware
I am using supabase for authentication and next-intl for localisation, both require middleware. Everything works as expected however, when redirecting using return redirect("/"); it doesn't re-route to the localised url - what's the reason for this?
Here is my middleware code;
import { createServerClient } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ["ka", "en"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
});

export async function updateSession(request: NextRequest) {
  let intlResponse = intlMiddleware(request);

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return request.cookies.getAll();
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) => request.cookies.set(name, value));
          intlResponse = NextResponse.next({
            request,
          });
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            intlResponse.cookies.set(name, value, options)
          );
        },
      },
    }
  );

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (!user && request.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/account")) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
    url.pathname = "/sign-in";
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }

  return intlResponse;
}

root middleware file;
import { type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { updateSession } from "@/utils/supabase/middleware";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return await updateSession(request);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/",
    "/(ka|en)/:path*",
    "/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)",
  ],
};

